# Confusion around 'nested' try/catch statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, try-catch

Essentially I have an async function containing a try/catch that calls another async function also containing a try catch, and I'm getting a bit confused about how to properly implement what I'm doing. Some "pseudocode" showing my current implementation:

```
const main = async () => {
  try {
    const test = await secondFunc();
    console.log(test);

  } catch(err) {

    console.log('Found an error!');
    console.log(err);
  }

const secondFunc = async () => {
  try {
    await performSomeRequestExample();

  } catch(err) {
    if (err.x === 'x') {
      doSomething();
    } else {

      //********
      throw err;
      //********
  }

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the `throw(err)` (surrounded by the asterisks) to be caught by the `catch` in `main()` which will also call the `console.log('Found an error!')`, but what currently happens is the error is thrown from `secondFunc()`, the `catch` in `main()` is never hit and I get an unhandled promise rejection.

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your else ever reached? Also does anything change if you put a variable in front of that await in your second function?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to minimize using try/catch unless absolutely necessary. With `async` functions (or any functions that return a `Promise` object) you can usually simplify things by not worrying about try/catch blocks unless you need to do something specific with certain errors. You can also use `.catch` rather than try/catch blocks to make things easier to read.

For example your code above could be written like this:

```js
const main = async () => {
  const test = await secondFunc().catch(err => {
    console.log("Found an error from secondFunc!", err);
    throw err;  // if you want to send it along to main's caller
  });
  if (test) {
    console.log("Test", test);
  }
};

const secondFunc = () => {
  return performSomeRequestExample().catch(err => {
    if (err.x === "x") {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
};

const performSomeRequestExample = () => Promise.reject("bad");

main().then(
  () => console.log("worked"),
  err => console.log("failed from main", err)
);
```

In `secondFunc` we don't need to use `async` since we can just return the promise coming back from `performSomeRequestExample` and handle any failures in the `.catch`.

Comment: Don't assume he doesn't need the second function to be async for all you know performSomeRequestExample() is a fetch and needs to await and on top of that OP's code is incomplete and not reflective of what they really have.

Comment: True. If performSomeRequestExample doesn’t return a Promise then you could make it async or return a Promise that resolves to its return value

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
const secondFunc = async () => {
  performSomeRequestExample().then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a return before the await of performSomeRequestExample.

```
const secondFunc = async () => {
    try {
        return await performSomeRequestExample();
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.x === 'x') {
            console.log('x');
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

or you can also use .catch() after the awaited function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be like this

```
const main =  async() => {
try {
    const test = await secondFunc();
    console.log(test);

  } catch(err) {

    console.log('Found an error!');
    console.log(err);
  }
}

const secondFunc = async () => {
  //return await performSomeRequestExample();  //for success
  return await performSomeRequestExample(2); //for error
}

const performSomeRequestExample = async(abc=1) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(abc ==1){
      setInterval(resolve("yes"),400);
    }else{
      setInterval(reject("opps"),400);
    }
  });
}


main();
```

Test this code at this link:
https://repl.it/repls/JoyfulSomberTelevision